# Change Cell Color if One cell Is Greater Than Another

Tags: microsoft-excel

Im having a lot of trouble figuring this out and after a ton of search-fu I need to ask an expert. I need a formula that will change the background color of a cell in column G if its value is greater than the value of the cell next to it in column F. Ive tried all kinds of formulas and Im not sure if I need to select all cells in column G then go to Conditional Formatting>Highlight Cell Rules>Greater Than to apply a forumla or just use New Rule on a single cell and drag it out to the rest of the column. I seem to be finding conflicting answers.

Answer (score 4):

You would use the formula:

```
=G1>F1
```

[image]

Then you would apply it to All of Column G:

[image]